# Docker container cannot find copied files when started with docker compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a strange problem, which I dont understand. Ihave a docker image, which runs a simple node web app. This is the Dockerfile I use:

```
# Copy from node
FROM node:latest

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

When start a container with this image just using `docker run`, everything works and the behaviour is as expected. The files were copied correctly, the web app is running and when inspecting the container, I can see all files are there:

```
sudo docker exec -it d4c19c5f4bc7 bash
root@d4c19c5f4bc7:/usr/src/app# ls
Dockerfile  node_modules  package-lock.json  package.json  server.js
```

Now, when I start a container using the same image using `docker compose`, the container crashes and never fully boots. When inspecting the logs, node does not seem to find the `server.js`, which is needed to start the web app. How can this be missing, when it was in fact there, when using `docker run`?

```
sudo docker logs 8985259ba2b1
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:942
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/server.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:939:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:780:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.2.0
```

This is the docker-compose.yml that I use:

```
services:
  node-test-app-v3:
    image: <my-user-name>/node-test-app-v3
    volumes:
      - ../volume-things/:/usr/src/app/
    network_mode: bridge
    expose:
      - 80
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: <some-domain-for-my-reverse-proxy>
```

I do not understand how this can happen. Shouldn't the files be inside the container, as they have been copied there when this container was built? How can the files be found when using `docker run` and not when using `docker compose up`?

Is there a way to enter a container that is started through docker compose?

All help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Whats in `../volume-things/`? You're mounting this folder to `/usr/src/app/`, so everything that _was_ in `/usr/src/app/` in the container will be hidden.

Comment: I have a `test.html` file in there. I wanted to try out volumes by binding one file inside the app's directory

Comment: ...and if you delete that `volumes:` block, you'll actually run the code built into the image and get consistent results.

Answer (score 2):

So as `tkausl` and `David Maze` kindly pointed out, my volume binding replaced the files in the app's root directory and therefore `server.js` could not be found. Moving the volume bind to another directory  like `/usr/src/app/vol` fixed this issue.